# How can I detect the amount and the perimeter of the circles from the picture?

Tags: python, shapes, detection, area, detect

There's a imput picture of 'lead frame' and i've already finished mid-blur,binarize,find the edge,dilation & erosion , labelling.
Then,how can I detect the amount and the perimeter of the circles from the picture without any library like openCV or something?

code for mid-blur：

```
mid_blur = img_gray[:] 
for y in range(len(img_gray)):
    for x in range(y):
        mid_blur[y,x]=img_gray[y,x]

members=[img_gray[0,0]]*9
for y in range(1,img_gray.shape[0]-1):
    for x in range(1,img_gray.shape[1]-1):      ########setting the components########
        members[0] = img_gray[y-1,x-1]
        members[1] = img_gray[y,x-1]
        members[2] = img_gray[y+1,x-1]
        members[3] = img_gray[y-1,x] 
        members[4] = img_gray[y,x]
        members[5] = img_gray[y+1,x]
        members[6] = img_gray[y-1,x+1]
        members[7] = img_gray[y,x+1]
        members[8] = img_gray[y+1,x+1]

        members.sort()
        mid_blur[y,x]=members[4]
```

code for dilation and erosion：

```
############dilation############
#Acquire size of the image
p,q= edgepic.shape       
imgDilate= np.zeros((p,q), dtype=np.uint8)    #######Define the new image of dilation########
#Define the structuring element 
SED= np.array([[0,1,0], [1,1,1],[0,1,0]])       ##########dilate matrix#######
constant1=1            
for i in range(constant1, p-constant1):
  for j in range(constant1,q-constant1):
    temp= edgepic[i-constant1:i+constant1+1, j-constant1:j+constant1+1]
    product= temp*SED                       ##############formula of dilation###########
    imgDilate[i,j]= np.max(product)

#########erosion##########
#Acquire size of the image
m,n= imgDilate.shape 
k=3     ###########size of structuring element#############
SE= np.ones((k,k), dtype=np.uint8)
constant= (k-1)//2
imgErode= np.zeros((m,n), dtype=np.uint8)          #######Define the new image of erosion########
#Erosion without using inbuilt cv2 function for morphology
for i in range(constant, m-constant):
  for j in range(constant,n-constant):
    temp= imgDilate[i-constant:i+constant+1, j-constant:j+constant+1]
    product= temp*SE
    imgErode[i,j]= np.min(product)
```

[This is the picture that i've already labeled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Un5N.jpg)

Comment: Please rewrite your post with proper grammar and formatting. Include the picture you mentioned and the code you are trying to use.

Comment: I would use [Hough Circles](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html).

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow I add the pic what i've done on the post.Thx

Comment: @Tommy225 Please post the code are you using for mid-blur, dilation, erosion, _etc._

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow OK！Sorry,this is the first time i use this website to ask question,so i'm not sure how to ask...